# loading additional scss files or code based on the chosen locale

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-lazyloading, angular-localize

I'm writing an angular 11 universal application with localization.

what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to load more `scss` files based on the locale chosen.

so for example if the user chose `Hebrew` it will add `styles-he.scss` that added `direction:rtl`.

I googled a lot and basically all say the same as this url: https://juristr.com/blog/2019/08/dynamically-load-css-angular-cli/

that I need to add the new style in my angular.json so it will be lazy loaded:

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          {
            "input": "src/styles-he.scss",
            "bundleName": "hebrewStyle",
            "inject": false
          }
   ...
```

and then I should create a loadStyle component in `app.component.ts`:

```
loadStyle(styleName: string) {
    const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    let themeLink = this.document.getElementById(
      'client-theme'
    ) as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (themeLink) {
      themeLink.href = styleName;
    } else {
      const style = this.document.createElement('link');
      style.id = 'client-theme';
      style.rel = 'stylesheet';
      style.href = `${styleName}`;

      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  }
```

and execute `loadStyle('styles-he.scss')` whenever I want

ahhh.. actually the tutorial talked about `css`, don't know if `scss` would work. probably I must use css in this method.

the thing is that I expected that there would be of a more angular way to include these style files based on countries. didn't quite understand when I execute this function and how do I know which language it is.

this is my locale configuration in `angular.json`

```
 "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en",
        "locales": {
          "he": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.he.xlf",
            "baseHref": "he/"
          }
        }
      },
```

so in general I'm lost in what's the proper way to add more styles based on the locale chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so i found a cool solution on stackoverflow for this.

i learned how to inject locale from [How To Use LOCALE_ID In Angular i18n Router Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333266/how-to-use-locale-id-in-angular-i18n-router-module) and the cool method from here:

[change Style sheet when different language is selected.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702355/change-style-sheet-when-different-language-is-selected)

i'm actually gonna have one file of css, but i can determine the language from the css file itself, which is actually a better solution then having separate files.

so this is what I did:

in the `app.component.ts` i did this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,....)

 ngOnInit(): void {
   document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', this.locale);
 }
}
```

I injected the locale, and i set a `lang` attribute on the document with the locale value

then in each scss style file for a component, i can add this:

`:host-context([lang="he"]){ ... }`

I learned it from here:
[Access body lang in SCSS in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076282/access-body-lang-in-scss-in-angular-6)

this way i'm not loading any css files dynamically with `loadStyle` function that i posted on my question and i don't need to lazy load anything.

this answer was updated after testing it on angular 15

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
`  
const lang ;


export function getStyle(){
    return lang == 'ar'? ['../../../assets/scss/ar/rtl.scss', '../../../assets/scss/ar/ar-style.scss']: ['../../../assets/scss/en/bootstrap.scss', '../../../assets/scss/en/en-style.scss'];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-category',
  templateUrl: './all-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: getStyle(),
})`
```

Comment: lang still needs to be filled with data. I googled and I can inject LOCALE_ID in the constructor, but how can the getStyle() function get that locale?

Comment: yes lang still needs to be filled .. i didn't fill it because "i thought you have issue on getting styles not on getting the lang "
you could get the lang using this

const arr = window.location.pathname.split("/");

export function getStyle(){
    return arr[1] == 'ar'? ['../../../assets/css/ar/rtl.scss', '../../../assets/scss/ar/ar-style.scss']: ['../../../assets/scss/en/bootstrap.scss', '../../../assets/scss/en/en-style.scss'];
}

Comment: thanks for your help, but the getStyle function returns an error that Value could not determined statically.